# Name of this modulo operation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, rational-numbers

I am looking for an operator on $\mathbb{Q}$ that is similar to the modulo operator, but gives me the smallest representative of the class $[0,p]$ instead of $[0,p)$.

Let's call it $\mod'$.

For example:

$\frac{1}{2} \mod ' \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$ and

$d \mod ' \frac{1}{2} = d - \frac{1}{2}, d \in \mathbb{Q}, 1 > d > \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: What do you mean by "cut"?  $4$ is $>3$ but $4\equiv 1 \pmod  3$

Comment: Please [edit] the question to give us more examples. Don't use the word "modulo". Imagine you are "cutting" all the numbers greater than $1/2$ and tell us what that operation does to $-1$, $0$, $1/4$, $1/2$, $3/4$, $1$ and $2$. Also tell us similar results for "cutting" with $\pi$.

Comment: @Gunnar This is a great way to put it into the words

Comment: @Gunnar could you post your answer again, I think it expressed what I was really intending to formalize. I know it does not fit with how I edited the question maybe I should reformulate it again.

Comment: You know that you can take $\mathbb{Q} \mod \frac{1}{2}$, and that a minimal set of representatives then is $[0, \frac{1}{2}) \cap \mathbb{Q}$. However, you seem to want $[0, \frac{1}{2}] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ to be the minimal set of representatives, maybe for something similar to modulo. If this is the case, then it would be a good idea to explain exactly why you are interested in this, and what properties you would like to hold. Do you for instance still want the number $3$ to have a unique representative in your set? Do you want to be able to add representatives and get another representative?

Comment: Yes, I want the unique representative of 3 to be $\frac{1}{2}$. Maybe it would make sense to define the minimal set of representatives as $(0,\frac{1}{2}]$?

Comment: In normal modulo we would really treat $0$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ as the same number when looking at the numbers $\mod \frac{1}{2}$. You can therefore choose to replace $0$ with  $\frac{1}{2}$ in your set of representatives if you want. It only gets awkward if you want to keep both of them at the same time, as there will not really be any algebraic way of distinguishing those numbers.

Comment: That's a good point

Answer (score 1):

The modulo operation does not "cut" anything or any numbers, it just says you the smallest representative of the class.  if you want to really cut all numbers greater 1/2 just declare a function f(x)=x for x<=1/2 , f(x)=0 for x>1/2.

Comment: Yes, as far as I understand it, modulo gives me the smallest representative of the class $[0,p)$, but I want it to return the smallest representative of the class $[0,p]$. Does that make any sense?

Comment: no, it does not what has it to do with 1/2